# How to pause a multiplayer game of Civilization IV in OS X?

Tags: civilization-4, macos

I know that the pause key pauses the game's turn timer in Windows, but how do you do it in OS X?

Comment: Have you tried F15, if your keyboard has that?

Comment: It's a _turn-based_ strategy game - by definition it is always paused

Comment: @HorusKol: If you're playing hot-seat multiplayer (many players, one keyboard) you can set a turn timer to stop one person from holding up the game too much.

Comment: would opening the menu work?

Comment: There *is* a paused mode in the game. It is used when you don't want the timer to run out. The game *does* run in real time (simultaneous moves), but limited to a certain amount of moves per turn. The option isn't in the menu - it's the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing **F15** (above the Page Up key on a Mac keyboard, in the same location that the Pause key is on a PC keyboard) will pause the game in the Mac version of Civ 4. I just tested this out myself.

Comment: @Sergio, while I agree that Macs sometimes [can feel different for difference's sake](http://superuser.com/q/249301/442) ("Think different"), there's no need to be this, er, _boombastic_ about it. You don't have to use OSX, you probably don't use it either, nor do I, so we don't really know what we're talking about here and at any rate we don't have any ground to judge Brant's choice.

Comment: I guess this is only really useful of those macs that have a F15 key on them. :)